# ask one agent set to get a value from another agent set

Tags: netlogo, agents

My sellers set trade_Price with this code:

```
ask buyers  [ ask sellers [if any? buyers-here [ if seller_Price <= [buyer_Price] of myself 
       [ set trade_Price  seller_Price + random ([buyer_Price] of myself - seller_Price) ]]]]
```

I want that my buyers also took the same trade_Price if they have a seller in the same patch.(if any? sellers-here). and I code it so:

```
ask sellers [ ask buyers [if any? sellers-here [set trade_Price ( [trade_Price] of myself )]]]
```

I think its wrong code because I got different trade_Price s from my agent couples.
Do you have any idea how can I set it?
Best reagrds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're trying for something like this:

```
ask buyers [
  let candidate one-of sellers-here
  if candidate != nobody [
    set trade_Price [trade_Price] of candidate
  ]
]
```

Note that there is no `ask sellers` around this. You only want each buyer to run this once each time through `go`.

Note that if there are multiple sellers on the patch, `one-of sellers-here` picks one randomly.

Comment: thank you, it runs:) and I have one more question.
in some patches i have "lonely" seller without buyer or lonely buyer without seller. in this case I code it so that their trade_Price is 0. in plot I want to show trade_Price. I code it so : plot mean [trade_Price] of turtles will it calculate the trade_Price which are 0 or? I want that it calculates only trade_Prices which are > 0. how can I code it in plot ?

Comment: If my answer works, then you can thank me by accepting it (using the big checkmark next to it). To ask a new question, open a new question.

Comment: I can ask only one question in 90 min :(